# Deny access to member directories

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

Is there a way to stop people from accessing directories where all my members file's are stored.

For example, I have mysite.com/members/$mem_id and in there that particular members files are stored, such as images. Is there a way to stop all of these been accessed directly from the URL bar, without placing index.php in every folder, possibly with .htaccess?

Also, once the folders have being blocked, the site itself still needs to access the files in them to display round the site.

Comment: The best way is to move the files outside your www root. The next best thing is to use .htaccess if that's not an option.

Comment: I tried .htaccess in just the members folder, but then the images wouldn't load on the site with "deny from all", so what could I put in htaccess instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable directory listing you can use .htaccess and adding this line

`Options -Indexes`